# How do we find ideals the ring $\mathbb R[X_0, X_1, ..., X_n,...]$? How do we show that each of these ideals are not finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

$\mathbb R[X_0, X_1, ..., X_n,...]$ is polynomial a ring in infinitely many variables over $\mathbb R$.

Can someone please explain ideals to me?

How do we show that $<X_0>$ is an ideal of the ring, $<X_0,X_1>$ is an ideal of the ring, $<X_0,X_1,...X_n,...>$ is an ideal of the ring and so on are ideals of the ring?

How do we show that each of these ideals are not finitely generated?

Please show and explain.

I ask this because I have been shown that ascending chain of ideals stabilizes iff the ideals of the ring are finitely generated. With respect to the ring in this problem, I want to understand how we found the ideals of the ring and how having deals that are not finitely generated does not meet the ascending chain conditions on ideals. Eventually, I will have to prove that the ring is non-Noetherian but I seek help with these basic steps. Please help.

Comment: What is $\langle X_0 \rangle$? If it means the ideal generated by $X_0$, then it is by definition an ideal, and, of course, is finitely generated, and even principal.

Answer (score 5):

Each $\left<X_0,\ldots,X_n\right>$ is a finitely-generated ideal.
But $I=\left<X_0,\ldots,X_n,\ldots\right>$ generated by **all** the $X_n$
is not finitely generated. To see this consider $I/I^2$. This is an
ideal for $R/I$ where $R$ is the ring in question. But $R/I\cong \Bbb R$
and if $I$ were finitely generated over $R$ then $I/I^2$ would be
a finite-dimensional vector space over $R/I$. But the images of
the $X_n$ are linearly independent elements of $I/I^2$. So $I/I^2$
is an infinite-dimensional vector space, and $I$ cannot be a finitely
generated ideal.

Comment: So, when we have $x_0 \in R$, then it generates $I=<X_0>$. This is a finitely generated ideal and a principal ideal since it is generated by a single element. But since each ideal becomes larger (compared to the previous one) without bound,  then the ideal generated by all the element in R is not finitely generated since it is generated by an infinite number of elements?